# How to prove that there is a positive integer $n_0$ such that$a_n = a_1 + \ldots + a_{n-1} $ for all $n \geq n_0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

> Let $a_1 < a_2 < \ldots$ be an infinite increasing sequence of positive integers such that $a_n$ divides $a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_{n-1}$ for $n \geq 2024$. Prove that there is a positive integer $n_0$ such that$a_n = a_1 + \ldots + a_{n-1}
> $
> for all $n \geq n_0$.

**My try**：there is a sequence$x_{2024}, x_{2025}, \ldots$ of positive integers such that for all $n \geq 2024$
.we have $a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_{n-1} = x_na_n.$

Substituting $n$ with $n+1$,we obtain
$x_{n+1}a_{n+1} = x_na_n + a_n = a_n(x_n + 1)$

Therefore
$x_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}(x_n + 1) < x_n + 1$ ⟹ $x_{n+1} \leq x_n$ for $ n \geq 2024$,(since$a_n < a_{n+1}$)

How can i continue?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Almost there! You now have an infinite amount of positive integers: $$x_n\geq x_{n+1}\geq x_{n+2}\geq\ldots\geq 1$$ What can you say will eventually happen?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout I didn't get it，could you explain that in detail?:）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a [Proof by infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent). Continuing what you have done:
Since $(x_n)\subset \mathbb N$ is decreasing, by the
[Well ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle), there are some $d, n_0\in\mathbb N$ such that: $$ x_n=d,\;\;\forall n\ge n_0.$$ Then your equality $$x_{n+1}a_{n+1}=x_na_n+a_n,\; \text{for } n\ge2024$$ becomes  $$da_{n+1}=da_n+a_n,\; \text{for } n\ge n_0,$$ hence we get $$ a_{n+1}=\frac{d+1}{d}a_n,\;\; \text{for } n\ge n_0.$$
Now $d+1$ and $d$ are [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers), so $d$ must divide $a_n$ for $n\ge n_0$, let $(b_n)_{n\ge n_0}\subset \mathbb N_{>0}$ such that $a_n=db_n$, so that new sequence satisfies $$db_{n+1}=(d+1)b_n,\;\; \text{for } n\ge n_0\implies b_{n+1}=\frac{(d+1)}{d}b_n,\;\; \text{for } n\ge n_0. $$
Now we can repeat the previous argument for the new sequence $(b_n)_{n\ge n_0}$ and find another sequence $(c_n)_{n\ge n_0}\subset \mathbb N_{>0}$ such that $b_n=dc_n$ for $n\ge n_0$. By iterating that argument we will find an infinite number of sequences $(a_n)_{n\ge n_0}, (b_n)_{n\ge n_0}, (c_n)_{n\ge n_0},\ldots$ such that one sequence is $d$ times the next sequence.

**contradiction**: If $d>1$, then we can find infinite number of integers $$a_{n_0}=db_{n_0}>b_{n_0}=dc_{n_0}>c_{n_0}>\ldots>0,$$ and this will cause our contradiction.